# My display menu repeats multiple times when an input is entered

Tags: python, class, object

I'm practice classes and inheritance in a program idea that I came up with myself. Basically Im making an arcade game menu simulator that can play two modes, single player and multiplayer. Every time I enter a choice, either 1 or 2, the menu displays a couple times and then it proceeds to accept the input, I only want the menu to be displayed once. Heres my code:

```
    # Suppose you are at an arcade and you and your friend want to play a multiplayer game that requires UI.
# Make the game ask for the users name and age to see if they can play, make the program so that it can add a friend.
# If any of the players are under the age of 18, they are not allowed to  play, otherwise proceed.
# **EXTRA CREDIT** --> Add a functionality which adds the players to a list until the list reaches 4 players, then stop adding to the list.

# arcade_game.py
import sys


# give the user a greeting
import self as self

lst = []


class menu:
    def __init__(self, ready):
        self.ready = ready

    #display menu
    @classmethod
    def display_menu(self):
        print("Pick from one of the choices below, type in the corressponding number")
        print("1. single player \n"
              "2. Multiplayer")
        choice = int(input("Enter your choice here: "))
        return choice

    # ready or not function to see if the user is ready to play
    def ready_or_not(self):
        # see if user types 1 or 2 with try & except
        try:
            # ask user if they are ready
            self.ready = int(input("Are you ready to play? Type 1 for yes, 2 for no"))
            self.display_menu()
        except ValueError:
            print("You did not type 1 or 2, please try again!")


# add players class
class player(menu):
    # add a default player to __init__(), **(since there has to be at least one player)**
    def __init__(self, ready, player1):
        super().__init__(ready)
        self.player1 = player1

    # single player method
    def set_name(self):
        self.player1 = input("Enter your name for single player mode")
        print("Lets play! ", self.player1)

    # multiplayer method
    def set_names(self):
        try:
            self.player1 = input("Enter your name to begin")
            lst.append(self.player1)
            # add another player to continue
            while len(lst) <= 4:
                add = input("Add player here: ")
                lst.append(add)
                if len(lst) == 4:
                    print("Player limit reached!")
                    break;
        except ValueError:
            print("You didnt enter valid input, please try again")

    # get the names of the players only if 1 is picked from display_menu() above, including player1
    def check_choice(self):
        if self.display_menu() == 1:
            self.set_name()
        elif self.display_menu() == 2:
            self.set_names()
        else:
            print("Exiting....")
            print("Goodbye!")
            sys.exit(0)


m = menu("yes")
m.ready_or_not()
p = player("yes", "test")
p.check_choice()
```

Comment: can you show your output? or try adding `input('')` and debug where exactly is the code duplicating the menu code

Comment: @Surya Tej                                                                                                    Are you ready to play? Type 1 for yes, 2 for no1
Pick from one of the choices below, type in the corressponding number
1. single player 
2. Multiplayer
Enter your choice here: 2
Pick from one of the choices below, type in the corressponding number
1. single player 
2. Multiplayer
Enter your choice here: 2
Pick from one of the choices below, type in the corressponding number
1. single player 
2. Multiplayer
Enter your choice here: 2
Enter your name to begin

Comment: When I add input in the menu method, it still repeats but with a blank whitespace @SuryaTej

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ready_or_not` calls `self.display_menu()`:

```
def ready_or_not(self):
    # see if user types 1 or 2 with try & except
    try:
        # ask user if they are ready
        self.ready = int(input("Are you ready to play? Type 1 for yes, 2 for no"))
        self.display_menu()
    except ValueError:
        print("You did not type 1 or 2, please try again!")
```

`check_choice` also calls `self.display_menu()` at least once, and twice if you type anything other than `1` the first time:

```
def check_choice(self):
    if self.display_menu() == 1:
        self.set_name()
    elif self.display_menu() == 2:
        self.set_names()
    else:
        print("Exiting....")
        print("Goodbye!")
        sys.exit(0)
```

Your top-level code calls `ready_or_not()` on one menu instance:

```
m = menu("yes")
m.ready_or_not()
```

… and `check_choice()` on another:

```
p = player("yes", "test")
p.check_choice()
```

So, your program displays the menu twice, and then a third time if you type anything but `1`.

If you don't want the menu displayed two or three times, don't call the method two or three times.

---

If you want to display the menu only once and remember the choice, instead of displaying it two or three times, you need to use that `self.ready` attribute that you create in `ready_or_not`, instead of calling the method again.

However, that still isn't going to work as-is, because your class design is weird. You've made two separate instances, `m` and `p`, each of which has its own independent attributes. I'm not sure why `player` inherits from `menu` in the first place (or why `display_menu` is a `@classmethod`, or why it calls its parameter `self` rather than `cls` if it is one, and various other things), but, given that a `player` is a `menu` in your design, you probably just want a single `player` instance, like this:

```
p = player("yes", "test")
p.ready_or_not()
p.check_choice()
```

And then, you can change `check_choice` like this:

```
def check_choice(self):
    if self.choice == 1:
        self.set_name()
    elif self.choice == 2:
        self.set_names()
    else:
        print("Exiting....")
        print("Goodbye!")
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Makes a ton of sense, I was thinking of that but wasnt 100% sure, Thanks a lot! appreciate your help! @abamert

Comment: @nathan Could you please explain how you are using `@classmethod` in your code

Answer (score 0):

> Took me a while to figure out, but it seems like when you are done with `display_menu()` your calling `ready_or_not()` so you need to remove `display_menu()` from ready or not like this

```
   # ready or not function to see if the user is ready to play
    def ready_or_not(self):
        # see if user types 1 or 2 with try & except
        try:
            # ask user if they are ready
            self.ready = int(input("Are you ready to play? Type 1 for yes, 2 for no"))
#            self.display_menu()
        except ValueError:
            print("You did not type 1 or 2, please try again!")
```

## EDIT

> looks like im late to the party